# Using git for only edited files and not the complete source?

Tags: git, github, push

I was wondering what the best way to use github is when working with 50gb+ source codes.
I will only change some files which are not that big but I would like to have those edits pushed to github but all the originial code can stay on my device without being pushed. I also would like the edited files to stay in the correct source map and not having to move them each time for pushing.
What is the best way to do this with git?

Comment: Git LFS may be useful: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can achieve what you ask for with .gitignore https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore. Just ignore files and folders that should not be committed.

If you need to ignore the folder, but still include some files/folders inside, it is also possible (with some quirks [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)).

Whether this is the best way or not depends on why you are not committing the entire source code.